# How to output to the Oculus and a 2D screen?

Tags: unity, camera, networking, screen, oculus

We'd like to present an Oculus game to a large group of people. Not everyone will have an Oculus headset, so we'd like to output to both the Oculus and a second display. The problem is that the project uses an Oculus plugin to render its output, so all they output is two distorted circles, which doesn't display well when not wearing the Oculus headset.

I thought of making a second Unity client (the "audience" client, running on the same computer as the Oculus application) that receives the output texture of an "audience" camera from the client running the Oculus version.

My question is: Can I use the network to send the output of a camera to the "audience" client so I can set it up for the second display, bypassing the Oculus plugin? How would I get the input on the "audience" client to map it to the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Best solution

Run an [OVR Mirror](http://stereoarts.jp/) and display another output window on your projector/monitor. You can attach it to one of the OVR 'eyes' if you are feeling lazy, or create a new camera and run it from there for better performance.

## Using networking

You would run the client in 2 ways:

1. Directly answering your question: To Remotely see everything **exactly** from the "main camera", means rendering on the original program/host. This is done using a [render texture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html). Now divide this texture up into an array of coloured pixels, and send this multi-million length array to the remote client as a message... for every frame. Expect delays, low resolution and [high complexity](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/190340/how-can-i-send-a-render-texture-over-the-network.html).
2. A **better** way of using networking to mirror a scene is to run the program like a "multiplayer game" where everything has a *network view* attached to it and is replicated on the secondary app. Essentially you are connecting a "spectator" to the game. This still adds complexity because "single-player" games are often hard to convert to "multiplayer".

## Another way without networking

Use the oculus in extended view, and run the app in a super-widescreen resolution [popup window](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html). Render your "Main_Camera" in one half of the resolution, and the Rift viewports on the other half. This is similar to OVR Mirror windows, without window boxes but less predictable (very dependent on specific resolution, monitor placement etc).